# JSON files searchable in Azure Storage

Tags: azure, apache-spark, elasticsearch, azure-blob-storage, databricks

Im looking for a cost efficient and easy way to index loads of JSON files.
It will be a number of different types of JSON data, each collected in its own folder in Azure Storage Containers.

I want to be able to search for some properties, however not all properties need to be searchable.

JSON data could look something like:

```json
{
  "schemaVersion": "1.0.0",
  "contentSource": "ABC",
  "id": "SC-366-AA",
  "lastModified": "2024-01-13T19:52:33.000+00:00",
  "eventType": "Sales",
  "eventTime": "2024-01-13T19:52:33.000+00:00",
  "data": {
    "seller": "Benny",
    "sellerId": "3982309009129",
    "title": "sales",
    "start": "2024-01-01",
    "end": "2024-12-01",
    "value": "2919"
  }
}
```

*Note: This is just an example, will be a lot more properties.*

I want to be able to do queries such as fetching all files with `lastModified` between x and y. Or simply find the files with a specific `id`.

I know this could be in a database, such as Cosmos DB, and then be queryable. But this is not what I am looking for.

My research have found these alternatives:

- Azure AI Search (previously Azure Cognitive Search) -  Allow for basically full search on all properties in JSON files
- Blog Index Tags -  Allows for up to 10 key/value pairs per blob
- Elasticsearch for Azure  - Seems very customizable

And Ive gotten some recommendations to use, since I am using Azure Storage Gen2:

- Azure Synapse Analytics
- Azure Databricks with Spark-based big data queries

Personally I do find Azure AI Search seems to fit the task the best, or Elasticsearch (which I have used previously in AWS). However interested what is best option in Azure, as that is somewhat new to me.

AI Search seems to very expensive however if you have a lot of data. Also I do not really need any AI power

Blog Index Tags seems a bit limited, and could quickly be outgrown.

Databricks and Synapse seems more fitted for research, where you may want to do some calculations or analysis on data from time to time, and it seems powerful. But it is very UI centric and somewhat cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

As you're asking for an opinion, all I can say is that - as you found - for this sort of task is exactly what Azure AI Search was designed: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-index-json-blobs

You can create an index over known, consistent model properties and continue to add JSON documents to storage that the indexer would watch: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage

Ultimately, depending on your needs, something else could work better, but Azure AI Search is probably a good generalized approach.

Comment: Thank you, and yes, it could be somewhat opinion based. But looking for the correct tooling, as not to use a hammer for everything. Seems like a resonable easy task that should be something many does, so not looking for just opinions, but also industry standard maybe?

Comment: Also is my assumptions for Synapse, Databricks and Spark correct? Because people I trust do "recommend that", but I cannot see it being best option during my research.

Comment: There's no industry standard. As you've already discovered, the right tool depends on your needs. All I can say is that this is a common scenario for which Azure AI Search was designed. I worked on the client libraries and we have several examples that do this very thing.

Comment: However, it AI search seems extremely pricey. And AI search, I do not want any AI assistance 